# Google Cloud SQL / MySQL IAM Authentication Denied for Service Account Through Cloud SQL Go Connector

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I'm setting up a Google Cloud service and Cloud SQL DB using MySQL and Go, and per the recommendations am trying to use automatic authentication through IAM, connecting with Cloud SQL Go Connector. The database is opening successfully, but upon attempted access I'm getting

`Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '<username>'@'cloudsqlproxy~<random IP address>' (using password: YES)`

The root user on the DB instance has a password set, the iam_authentication flag is on for the database, and the service account

`<username>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

has Cloud SQL Client and Cloud SQL Instance User roles, and is listed as a User on the database with

```
Username           <username>
Hostname           % (any host)
Authentication     IAM (service account)
Password status    N/A
```

I wrote `grant select on <table> to "<username>";` to the database for the only table I'm attempting to access, and had previously tried `grant all on <database>.* to "<username>";`

My function to connect, using the connection code here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/HEAD/cloudsql/mysql/database-sql/connect_connector_iam_authn.go is

```
func connectWithConnectorIAMAuthN() (*sql.DB, error) {
    var (
        dbUser = "<username>"                          
        dbName = "<database name>"     
        instanceConnectionName = "<project>:<zone>:<database instance>" 
    )

    d, err := cloudsqlconn.NewDialer(context.Background(), cloudsqlconn.WithIAMAuthN())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("cloudsqlconn.NewDialer: %v", err)
    }

    var opts []cloudsqlconn.DialOption
    mysql.RegisterDialContext("cloudsqlconn",
        func(ctx context.Context, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return d.Dial(ctx, instanceConnectionName, opts...)
        })

    dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("%s:empty@cloudsqlconn(localhost:3306)/%s?parseTime=true",
        dbUser, dbName)

    dbPool, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbURI)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("sql.Open: %v", err)
    }

    return dbPool, nil
}
```

Could anybody help direct me to what I'm missing? I'd seen in an older SO entry that MySQL had previously been unsupported with the Automatic IAM Authentication, but it looked as though that had changed.

I've attempted changing roles, created new Service Accounts, adding and removing granted access to the DB, attempted access with and without the service email, debugging through to verify where failure was occurring, and a lot of doc digging.

Comment: did you receive any error or is it working when you tried with `grant all on <database>.* to "<username>";`

Comment: Check the logs for additional information about the failed connection: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/logging

Comment: @SathiAiswarya Yeah, I got the same error with `grant all`. 
@JohnHanley Yeah, that message was pulled from the logs, there wasn't a whole lot more in there regarding the error.

Comment: Last night I tried essentially the exact same set of steps but with a new Cloud SQL instance set up in Postgres and the postgres/pgxv4 Connector and it worked immediately. I think support may just not be very good for MySQL yet.

Comment: What username are you using? For MySQL you have to strip off everything after the `@` sign.

Comment: The error message that you posted is a client error that is not descriptive for security reasons. In the Cloud SQL logs should be a more detailed error message. Which logs did you check?

Comment: @enocom I'd been using just `<username>` relative to the email address `<username>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` (so just the bit before the `@`

Comment: @JohnHanley I'd both filtered for the SQL specific stuff and looked through the logs unfiltered, but didn't find a whole lot more that was useful. After messing with the Postgres version that's working, I'm pretty sure it was due to creating and seeding the table via an imported SQL dump that might not have been closed properly.

Comment: How are you running your Go code? You could be running as an IAM principal other than your IAM user.

Comment: Which logs are you looking at (application or Cloud SQL)?